# Java CountDownLatch not unlock? why the last line not print?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

the countDownLatch will be not await after countDown() until zero. but the program is locked .  the last print never output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    countDownLatch.await();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    }).start();

    System.out.println("------should print-------");
}
```

if the await method is in a thread(not the main thread), it works. why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                countDownLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    }).start();

    System.out.println("------should print-------");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are calling await (and stopping the thread) before launching your sub-Thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    }).start();
    countDownLatch.await();
    System.out.println("------should print-------");
}
```

Comment: You are welcome :) If you could mark the thread as resolved by chosing an answer it would be awesome ;)